# what's best way to make a search form for a really small application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, sunspot

I'm using rails to make a simple search form in Rails (search news title and content, users name, etc). This app is hosted by Heroku. I took a look at sunspot but it seems it's not free (doesn't work for me). I'd like some suggestions about what should I do. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MetaSearch gem.

Meta Search is a robust database search engine that allows you to easily construct SQL-free search queries. You can easily make a search form using their interface. I use it, and I find it to be quite comprehensive.

[Meta Search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search)

It gives you all kinds of cool methods such as

```
User.search(:username_like => 'this', :username_not_like => 'that', :id_greater_than => 31)
```

and all sorts of other good stuff

Advanced queries from the GitHub page,

```
# Searches projects that have awesome users
Project.joins(:user).where(:users => {:awesome => true}).search(params[:search])
```

Comment: does it provide any kind of multiple model search support?

Comment: Yes, you can create advanced search queries using the `.joins` method. I believe there is an example on the GitHub page

Comment: outdated now, the suggested one now is ransack but ive made the decision to code my own (obviously cuz ransack didnt do what i want)

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Ransack gem](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/) it work good for me. and there is also a video on railscast on how to use it
hope this help

Answer (score 1):

If its something simple and you just want to fire and forget you could just do the noob thing and create a google custom search.

http://www.google.com/cse/

Its and easy fire and forget setup.

I believe you can even have it target certain routes so it would only return results from www.foobar.com/blog or www.foobar.com/users.